# MySQL Registration not working when updated to SQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli, registration

So I literally don't have much knowledge of the differences between MySQL and MySQLi, I will be picking it up slowly while I'm working... I am trying to use my old SQL PHP registration form on this new website and not having any luck, I am either getting `"mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given"` or blank pages or it's bringing back site errors such as `"Desired Username is a required field. Please enter it below."` when the field has been filled out? If someone could take a look, I'd be much appreciative! Thanks.

Register.php -

```
 <?php
if (isset($_GET['signuperror'])) {
    $signuperror = $_GET['signuperror'];
} else {//if there is no choice, display series 1
    $signuperror = 1; 
}

switch($signuperror) {

    case 1:
        echo '';
    break;

    case 2:
       echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>First Name is a required field. Please enter it below.</strong></span></div> ";
    break;

    case 3:
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Last Name is a required field. Please enter it below.</strong></span></div> ";
    break;

    case 4:
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Email Address is a required field. Please enter it below.</strong></span></div> ";
    break;

    case 5:
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Desired Username is a required field. Please enter it below.</strong></span></div> ";
    break;

    case 6:
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Your passwords do NOT match, please check your passwords.</strong></span></div> ";
    break;

    case 7:
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Your email address has already been used by another user. Please use a different Email address.</strong></span></div> ";
    break;

    case 8:
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>The username you have selected has already been used by another user. Please choose a different Username.</strong></span></div> ";
    break;

    case 9:
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>There has been an error creating your account. Please contact the admin.</strong></span></div> ";
    break;

    default:
    break;
}


?> 


              <form name="register" id="register" action="registercode.php" method="POST"> 
                 <div class="register-top-grid">
                    <h3>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h3>
                     <div class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                        <span><b>First Name</b><label>*</label></span>
                        <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your first name." maxlength="100" name="first_name" id="first_name" required> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                        <span><b>Last Name</b><label>*</label></span>
                        <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your last name." maxlength="100" name="last_name" id="last_name" required> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                         <span><b>Email Address</b><label>*</label></span>
                         <input type="email" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." size="68" name="email_address" id="email" required> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                       <a class="news-letter" href="#">
                         <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked=""><i> </i>Sign Up for Newsletter</label>
                       </a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="register-bottom-grid">
                            <h3>LOGIN INFORMATION</h3>
                            <div class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                        <span><b>Username</b><label>*</label></span>
                        <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid username." maxlength="100" name="username" id="username" required> 
                     </div><div class="clearfix"> </div><div class="clearfix"> </div><div class="clearfix"> </div><div class="clearfix"> </div>
                             <div class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                                <span><b>Password</b><label>*</label></span>
                                <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password" required>
                             </div>
                             <div class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                                <span><b>Confirm Password</b><label>*</label></span>
                                <input type="password" value="" name="passwordcheck" id="passwordcheck"  required>
                             </div>
                     </div>

                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                <div class="register-but">

                       <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" class="btn btn-info"> | Already a member? <a href="signin.php"><b>Login</b></a>
                       <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                   </form>
                </div>
           </div>
         </div>
    </div>
<!-- registration -->
```

registercode.php -

```
    <?

include 'core/init.php';

// Define post fields into simple variables
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
$email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email_address']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$passwordcheck = $_POST['passwordcheck'];

/* Let's strip some slashes in case the user entered
any escaped characters. */

$first_name = stripslashes($first_name);
$last_name = stripslashes($last_name);
$email_address = stripslashes($email_address);
$username = stripslashes($username);


/* Do some error checking on the form posted fields */

if((!$first_name) || (!$last_name) || (!$email_address) || (!$username) || (!$password) || (!$passwordcheck)){
    if(!$first_name){
        header('Location: register.php?signuperror=2');
    }
    if(!$last_name){
        header('Location: register.php?signuperror=3');
    }
    if(!$email_address){
        header('Location: register.php?signuperror=4');
    }
    if(!$username){
        header('Location: register.php?signuperror=5');
    }
    if ($password !== $passwordcheck){
        header('Location: register.php?signuperror=6');
    }

    include "register.php"; // Show the form again!
    /* End the error checking and if everything is ok, we'll move on to
     creating the user account */
    exit(); // if the error checking has failed, we'll exit the script!
}

/* Let's do some checking and ensure that the user's email address or username
 does not exist in the database */

 $sql_email_check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE email_address='$email_address'");
 $sql_username_check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

 $email_check = mysqli_num_rows($sql_email_check);
 $username_check = mysqli_num_rows($sql_username_check);

 if(($email_check > 0) || ($username_check > 0)){
    if($email_check > 0){
        header('Location: register.php?signuperror=7');
        unset($email_address);
    }
    if($username_check > 0){
        header('Location: register.php?signuperror=8');
        unset($username);
    }
    include 'register.php'; // Show the form again!
    exit();  // exit the script so that we do not create this account!
 }

/* Everything has passed both error checks that we have done.
It's time to create the account! */

$db_password = md5($password);

// Enter info into the Database.
$info2 = htmlspecialchars($info);
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users (email_address, username, first_name, last_name, password, reg_date, last_login, activated, admin)
        VALUES('$email_address', '$username', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$db_password', now(), now(), '0', '0')") or die (mysqli_error());

if(!$sql){
    header('Location: register.php?signuperror=9');
} else {
    $userid = mysqli_insert_id();
    // Let's mail the user!
    $subject = "Fundfeeder Accounts";
    $message = "Dear $first_name $last_name,
    Thank you for registering at Fundfeeder, http://www.fundfeeder.co.uk/

    You are one step away from logging in and accessing your account.

    To activate your membership, please click here: http://www.fundfeeder.co.uk/activate.php?id=$userid&code=$db_password

    Once you activate your memebership, you will be able to login with the information you provided.

    Thanks!
    FundFeeder Admin Team.

    This is an automated response, please do not reply!";

    mail($email_address, $subject, $message, "From: FundFeeder Accounts<admin@fundfeeder.co.uk>\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
    ////// MAIL ADMIN
    $subject2 = "FundFeeder New User!";
    $message2 = "Dear Admin,
    This is a message to alert you that a new user has signed up to FundFeeder.

    You can view all details of the new member and all other members direct from the admin control panel at http://fundfeeder.co.uk/admin.php

    Here are the details of the new registered user:
    Username: $username
    Email Address: $email_address

    Thanks!
    FundFeeder Accounts.

    This is an automated response, please do not reply!";

    mail('aidan6141@hotmail.co.uk', $subject2, $message2, "From: FundFeeder Accounts<admin@fundfeeder.co.uk>\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
    header('Location: signin.php?loginerror=6');
include 'signin.php';
}

?>
```

core/init.php (db connection) -

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.co.uk","u479096627_admin","password", "u479096627_ctrl");
//Evaluate the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: msqli_query needs two parameters 1 is db connection and 2nd the query.[see here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp). I suggest using prepared statements to remove possiblity of SQL Injection

Comment: The database connection is located in the "include core/init" section, would that not function as the db connection for the page?

Comment: wait I am putting the complete as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look in core/init.php to find where the mysqli connection is being made.  You should see something like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassword","mydb");
```

If that file hasn't been updated to use mysqli yet, it may look like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect('myhost', 'myuser', 'mypassword', 'mydb');
```

All you need to do there is change `mysql_connect` to `mysqli_connect` to have it use mysqli.

Then, you would run the query like so:

```
$sql_email_check = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE email_address='$email_address'");
```

For more information, reference the PHP manual for [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) and 
and [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Would I need to add that to every query then within the code?

Comment: Yes.  Or you could use the Object Oriented approach (probably better) and do this **$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');**.  Then your queries would look like this **$mysqli->query("SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE email_address='$email_address'")**

Comment: I have edited each query to include the $conn variable, but still not having any luck, I will update the answer to include the edits.

Comment: Include the portion of code where the connection is being made.

Comment: I have added the db connection above too for reference, is it better to have that on every single back page where a connection is being made? As with MySQL I could just use it on one page and the entire site would connect.

Comment: The **mysqli_** functions work the same way as **mysql_** functions.  You have to have a connection for either of them to work, so yes anywhere that you will be running queries, the connection portion has to be included.  But making the connection in the init.php page is fine and just include that page wherever you will be running queries. I presume you are no longer receiving the error about requiring two arguments?  If this is the case, then the problem has been solved.  Not sure what the problem is at this point...

Comment: Yeah that's not the issue at the moment, but I am still receiving one of my errors back when I issue the sign up request - no. 5 (Desired Username is a required field. Please enter it below.). No idea why this is showing but I have tried removing the username completely and it then shows error no. 4 instead, regarding emails. So something's not working...

Comment: Maybe something to do with the error checking section in the registercode.php? Does this change with the new MySQLi?

Comment: Again, the **mysqli_** functions work the same as the **mysql_** functions.

Comment: If the question has been answered, consider accepting it as the answer.  It sounds like you want someone else to fix your entire registration page, but this isn't really the appropriate venue for that.  You'll need to do some testing and if you hit another roadblock, then post another question.

Comment: That is still in the first question, if you read what I wrote it said I am either getting one of 3 errors. Your answer has helped in many ways but the first issue still remains :/

Comment: If the problem is with the username, then dump your post variables after submission and look a what you have (try adding **echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';** at the top of registercode.php).

Then look in the database and ensure the username is not in use.  Without being able to see the database, we can't error check from afar.

Comment: Note also that **mysqli_real_escape_string** _"Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection"_  So, in the next step, where you strip slashes, you are removing any escape characters you just added.  This doesn't make sense. You should escape the string just before doing the insert into the database.

Comment: Okay, I will try that out and will see if I get anywhere, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

you need to define db connection as a parameter for all msqli_connect statement.

a sample is here:

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
   $password = "password";
   $db ="database";

 // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

   // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
 ?>
```

Now when passing a query to msqli_query:

```
$query = "your-SQL-query";
$run = msqli_query($conn,$query);
if(!$run){
 //handle the error here if query fails
  }
```

to check for any row that already exists you need to pass the following
In this example case it will be:

```
      $row_check = mysqli_num_rows($run);
```

hope you now understand how to use msqli* functions.